# NiFi: How to get all ProcessorType via its REST API?

Tags: java, api, rest, apache-nifi

Using this NiFi API end-point `GET "/process-groups/{id}/processors"`, able to fetch all processors part of the root Process Group. Each Processor has a property called `"type"`. So to fetch all unique Processor Type (Example: ConsumeKafka), I can iterate through all processors and look for its `"type"` property.

Is there any existing NiFi REST end-point to fetch all unique "Processor Types"? If not, please suggest an easier way to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: There is no such endpoint. So, you have to write a script in a language you like.

Comment: @daggett Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nifi-api endpoint you probably want is /flow/processor-types.
There is a reference implementation in my NiFi Python client [NiPyAPI](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nipyapi-docs/nipyapi.html#nipyapi.canvas.list_all_processor_types)